# RealmDB results always showing empty

Tags: node.js, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-js

For a hobby project, I was trying to create and access the realm DB local using NodeJS SDK. I've created the DB (.realm file) with **realm studio and CSV file**, and **able to browse** the objects.

[image]

However, when I tried to connect with NodeJS SDK, I'm unable to query the data and DB instance always returning empty.

I've referred the documentation and other stack-overflow questions, but unable to find the root cause.

This is my code,

```
const Realm = require('realm');

const OlamDBSchema = {
  name: 'OLAM_DB',
  primaryKey: '_id',
  properties: {
    _id: 'string',
    english_word: 'string',
    part_of_speech: 'string?',
    malayalam_definition: 'string',
  },
};
async function execute() {
  try {
    const realm = await Realm.open({
      path: 'olam1', // olam1.realm file in same folder
      schema: [OlamDBSchema],
    });

    let dict = realm.objects('OLAM_DB');
    let result = dict.filtered("english_word == 'Abduct'"); // word exists
    console.log(result.length, realm.isClosed, realm.isEmpty); // always prints 0 false true
    realm.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

execute().then(() => {});
```

I'm using OSx 12.6, NodeJS 16.14 & realm 11.0.0

Could you please point out, what I'm doing wrong here. Any suggestions or feedbacks will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Best practice here on SO is to do some troubleshooting to narrow down the line of code that isn't working before posting questions. Please do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected. For example, is your Realm file stored at the `olam1` path? If not, there's your problem. Another thing to try, immediately after opening the realm, write something to it, then read it back. Does that work? Update your question and we'll take a look.

Comment: @Jay : Yes you are right, I should dig deep, before posting the question.  I issue was due to realm path. it was not throwing any issues to my invalid path. Docs are also poor related to path definition for NodeJS SDK.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the issue in my code. Sharing to you, if anybody gets into such a situation.

```
 const realm = await Realm.open({
      path: 'olam1', // path was given wrong, but SDK did not throw any error
    });
```

when I changed to a correct file path, everything worked OK.